# Why do i get NullPointerException in my input?

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception

i'm a beginner java programmer and i did some research but i cannot understand how to apply it to my program.

when i run my program, i get a `NullPointerException` as i enter the nickname for the first IP Address. Why?

the isolated line in the code is where i get the Exception.

Comment: I cannot tell what line you've "isolated".  ANY time you have an error, like a java exception, POST THE WHOLE THING.  It has LOTS of information in it that you haven't given us.  By the way, all your uses of "&" are probably supposed to be "&&" instead; both are legal operators in java, but mean different things.

Comment: sorry @arcy, i tried to make the line as noticeable as possible. also, this is the entire code. and the code is commented to explain my every action.  and thank you. i will make changes based on the legal operators tip.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing this line (before NullPointerException is thrown):

```
ipAddress[i] = new IPAddress();
```

You should initialize array's elements before.

Comment: @ShacoNotFound404 you cant assign your value before running contructor which makes your Ipaddress object. new IPAddress[2] is not making object, it just takes spaces for them. So you have to make them before you can change their states, values etc.

Answer (score 3):

You have created an `array` of Ip Adresses but you never filled in any IP adress.

Here `ipAddress[i].nickname = input.next();` you assume that `ipAddress[i]` holds an `IPAdress` object and try to set its `nickname` field to `input.next()`. But since you haven't added any objects to it, the array, is filled with the default value which is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate an array like this:

```
IPAddress[] ipAddress = new IPAddress[2];
```

it creates an array with two slots, but both of the slots have `null`. You need to put something in each slot before you can use it as an object:

```
ipAddress[i] = new IPAddress();
ipAddress[i].nickname = input.next();
```

Inside `local_address` you are going to get another NPE. You set `result` to `null` initially and don't assign an array to it. That's why you're getting a NPE. You can fix this with:

```
String[][] result = new String[addr.length][]; // instead of null
```

However, you will also need to assign a `String[]` for each value of `j`. If you don't know what `count` will grow to be, you might consider using a `List<String>` that can grow automatically for you.

As an aside: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but your logic doesn't look correct. Do you really need a two-dimensional `String` array? It seems like this should be what you want:

```
static List<String> local_address(IPAddress addr[]) {
    List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < addr.length; j++) {
        IPAddress test = addr[j];
        if (test.xx == addr[j + 1].xx & test.yy == addr[j + 1].yy) {
            result.add(addr[j + 1].nickname;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```